# "exited, segmentation fault" with struct

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

For my C++ code below, I have declared a pointer of the "node" struct called "newNode" (node *newNode) and am trying to enter an id # and input it into newNode->id. After I enter in an id #, I get an error saying "exited, segmentation fault". I understand that this means we are trying to access a location in memory that we do not have access to, but am not aware how to fix this problem. I appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node 
{
    int id;
    string name;
    int age;
    node *nxt;
};

node *head = NULL;

void InsertNode()
{
  node *currentNode, *newNode, *nextNode;

  cout << "You will now be prompted to enter the ID number, name, and age of a particular person..." << endl;
  cout << "Enter ID number: ";
  cin >> newNode->id;
  cout << "Enter name: ";
  cin >> newNode->name;
  cout << "Enter age: ";
  cin >> newNode->age;

  currentNode = head;

  while (currentNode != NULL)
  {
    if (newNode->id == currentNode->id)
    {
      cout << "The ID you entered was already assigned to another node. Please enter a different ID number for the node that you are inserting: " << endl;
      cin >> newNode->id;
    }else{
      currentNode = currentNode->nxt;
    }
  }

  if (head == NULL)
  {
    head = newNode;
  }else{
    currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
      nextNode = currentNode->nxt;
      if (newNode->id < nextNode->id)
      {
        if(currentNode == head)
        {
          head = newNode;
          newNode->nxt = nextNode;
        }else if (nextNode->nxt == NULL && newNode->id > nextNode->id)
        {
          newNode->nxt = NULL;
          nextNode->nxt = newNode;
        }else{
          newNode->nxt = nextNode;
        }
      }else{
        currentNode = nextNode;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  InsertNode();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use a pointer you need to point it at something.

Comment: [Turn on compiler warnings, and the compiler will diagnose many categories of mistakes](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cT9Yc6fxf).

Answer (score 0):

You have only created pointers that can point to a node of struct type but you haven't actually allocated memeory for these structures ..That is why you are getting segmentation fault as you are trying access a location that is not there .
First create a struct node via dynamic memory allocation say malloc and then try to assign I'd to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a pointer to a struct, and when you're trying to insert something in the place of the pointer, but the pointer doesn't point to an object of the struct.

You need to dynamically allocate the node for insertion.

```
node *currentNode, *newNode, *nextNode;

newNode = new node(); // <- this is what you need to do, so you can insert. 

  cout << "You will now be prompted to enter the ID number, name, and age of a particular person..." << endl;
  cout << "Enter ID number: ";
  cin >> newNode->id;
  cout << "Enter name: ";
  cin >> newNode->name;
  cout << "Enter age: ";
  cin >> newNode->age;
```

Go forth and prosper.